# scala function to operate on any case class

Tags: scala, generics, case-class

I've been trying ot create a function that does some inflection on any case class but can't figure out how to pull it off on non concrete generic types, what am I doing wrong?

Please note I can't change the original case classes passed to this function
** edit ** forgot to mention I'm using pre 2.13 scala and prefer a solution that doesn't rely on external libraries.

```scala
        def caseClassToArray[A](something: A) = {
          classOf[A]
          .getDeclaredFields
          .map { f: Field =>
          f.setAccessible(true)
          val res = (f.getName, f.get(something))
          f.setAccessible(false)
          res
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with any case class? What is the meta-problem you are trying to solve? Is probably that the answer you want is a **Typeclass** + **Shapeless**.

Comment: @Luis the actual inflection is converting all fields in the class to an array of key value tuples, but I think that's relatively unimportant, actually reading this I see that I to mention I'm using scala 2.12 so I don't have access to some of the newer tools, another thing is that I prefer to solve this without any external libraries.

Comment: The thing is that the currently accepted solution is not type-safe, again **Shapeless** is probably the best way to solve this. What do you want to do with that list of key-value pairs?

Comment: making a kind of diff between two unknown objects

Comment: but can you explain what you mean by unsafe exactly?

Comment: What do I have to explain? The return type is `Array[(String, Any)]` the `Any` makes it unsafe, you don't know what will be there, it can be anything. Anyways, it seems [this library](https://diffx-scala.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) already does what you want. Otherwise, you may want to create your own approach based on **Shapeless** I can share with you the gist of that if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242209/discussion-between-noobaf-and-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what was discussed in comments, it seems the best solution would be a `Diff` **typeclass** and using **Shapeless** for the derivation for case classes.

The first step is to define the typeclass.

```scala
trait Diff[A] {
  def diff(a1: A, a2: A): A
}
```

> You may need to adjust the definition for your exact use case.

The next step is to provide support for basic std types like `Int`, `String`, `List[A]` for any `A` that has a `Diff`, etc

```scala
object Diff {
  implicit final val IntDiff: Diff[Int] =
    new Diff[Int] {
      override def diff(i1: Int, i2: Int): Int =
        i1 - i2
    }

  ...
}
```

> You may also want to add extension methods, `implicitNotFound` error message, and everything just like any other typeclass.
> That stuff is out of the scope of this answer.

The next step is to use **Shapeless** to inductively derive an instance for any `HList` for whose all element types have a `Diff` associated.

```scala
import shapeless.{:: => :!:, HList, HNil}

sealed trait ReprDiff[R <: HList] extends Diff[R]
object ReprDiff {
  implicit final val HNilReprDiff: ReprDiff[HNil] =
    new ReprDiff[HNil] {
      override final def diff(nil1: HNil, nil2: HNil): HNil = HNil
    }
  
  implicit def HConsReprDiff[H, T <: HList](
    implicit ev: Diff[H], tailReprDiff: ReprDiff[T]
  ): ReprDiff[H :!: T] = new ReprDiff[H :!: T] {
    override final def diff(hlist1: H :!: T, hlist2: H :!: T): H :!: T = {
      val headDiff = ev.diff(hlist1.head, hlist2.head)
      val tailDiff = tailReprDiff.diff(hlist1.tail, hlist2.tail)
      
      headDiff :: tailDiff
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, using **Shapeless** `Generic` magic we can provide an instance for any case class for which exist an instance of its `HList` representation.

```scala
import shapeless.Generic

sealed trait DerivedDiff[P <: Product] extends Diff[P]
object DerivedDiff {
  implicit def instance[P <: Product, R <: HList](
    implicit gen: Generic.Aux[P, R], ev: ReprDiff[R]
  ): DerivedDiff[P] = new DerivedDiff[P] {
    override final def diff(p1: P, p2: P): P =
      gen.from(ev.diff(gen.to(p1), gen.to(p2)))
  }
}
```

> `gen.to` turns any instance of a case class `P` into an `HList` that represents it.
> `gen.from` turns a matching instance of an `HList` into a `P`

Now, all we need is a way to let our users derive the instance for their case classes as long as all fields have a `Diff` associated with them.
I personally prefer the `semiauto` approach:

```scala
// Somewhere, like in the companion object of Diff
def derive[P <: Product](implicit ev: Deriving.DerivedDiff[P]): ev.type = ev
```

With all that, you can just use it like this:

```scala
final case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int)
object Foo {
  implicit final val FooDiff: Diff[Foo] =
    Diff.derive[Foo]
}
```

Congratulations, you now can `diff` two `Foo` instances:

```scala
val foo1 = Foo(1, 3)
val foo2 = Foo(0, 5)

val diff = Diff.diff(foo1, foo2)
// res: Foo = Foo(1, -2)
```

> In this example we added an auxiliary method `diff` in the `Diff` companion object; you may provide any other API to call the `diff` operation.

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/Wvlnypz9TTuAlaamJKzdmw/9)*.

Answer (score 7):

*If you are looking for a way to do reflection, the answer of @Silvio is good.*

However to achieve the same output, you should rely on standard methods provided by the library and not use reflection:

```scala
def caseClassToArray[A <: Product](instance: A): Array[(String, Any)] = {
  a.productElementNames.zipWith(a.productIterator)
}
```

See https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Product.html (all case classes inherit from `Product`).

Answer (score 4):

Scala, like Java, erases generic types at runtime. So if you want to do something at runtime with the generic type `A`, you need to take an [implicit `ClassTag` argument](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/reflect/ClassTag.html).

```
import scala.reflect._
import java.lang.reflect._

def caseClassToArray[A](something: A)(implicit cls: ClassTag[A]) = {
  cls.runtimeClass // <-- Instead of classOf[A]
    .getDeclaredFields
    .map { f: Field =>
      f.setAccessible(true)
      val res = (f.getName, f.get(something))
      f.setAccessible(false)
      res
    }
}
```

In Scala 3, that looks like

```
def caseClassToArray[A](something: A)(using cls: ClassTag[A]) = {
  ...
}
```